# Lubuntu 12.04 change default keyboard-layout after installation

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, default, language-support

I accidentally set the keyboard to the wrong language when I was installing the system, and now I have to change that keyboard setting every time i start the computer.

How do I change the default keyboard language in Lubuntu 12.04?

Comment: preferences->lxkeymap->select the language. click apply.

Comment: (at)lxpanel --profile                                       
(at)xscreensaver -no-splash
(at)xfce4-power-manager
(at)pcmanfm --desktop --profile lubuntu
(at)/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1

Comment: i replaced the at symbol with (at) due to some website setting problem.

Comment: and setback query returns: rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us

Comment: I want US, but the computer keeps starting up with Icelandic because that's what I clicked when installing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7436/discussion-between-vasa1-and-hermann-ingjaldsson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the following in the Terminal will change the keyboard setting to US for example:

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

And then you can make bash aliases such as `keybaord_layout us`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

To make a permanent change of the language of the keyboard, write this in the terminal:

```
 echo '@setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle "es, us"' | sudo tee -a /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

This sets the keyboard language to Spanish. This works for Lubuntu 12.04 too.

To just change the keyboard layout for the session, write this in the terminal (this example is for the english language):

```
setxkbmap -layout us
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem. After instalation of Lubuntu, keybord layout became US.
The following command helpd me to change it back to UK.  Thanks for those who started this thread.

```
setxkbmap -layout gb
```

Answer (score 0):

On 16.04.1 I right-clicked on the panel to choose 'Panel Settings'. From there I chose the 'Panel Applets' tab and added the 'Keyboard Layout Handler' applet. I used the Keyboard Layout Handler (right click on it in the bottom right-hand corner of the panel) to add the layout I wanted and remove the one I didn't need.