# I need keyboard layout help Lubuntu

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu

Running Lubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. My laptop has a compressed keyboard, everything -numpad. It seems that I need to notify Lubuntu of that. For example, the @ is under \ and vice versa. I can live with it but it'd be nice if someone knew how to change it. I'm running amd64

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lubuntu 12.04 change default keyboard-layout after installation.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252688/lubuntu-12-04-change-default-keyboard-layout-after-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You probably just set the wrong keyboard layout for your location during the installation. I don't think the missing numpad has anything to do with it.

For example, I live in the Netherlands but we use the United States keyboard layout. There is a Dutch keyboard layout as well, which is different (obviously), but I don't know what it's used for. Selecting the Dutch keyboard layout for United States keyboard layout causes Lubuntu to link the wrong values to the keys.

To change your keyboard layout, check this [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Keyboard) (at **Keyboard mapping for 13.10 and beyond**).